# Url Rewrite Using php & Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm stuck with this.I have a page in my website like `www.domainname.com/userhome.php?view=prsnl_pge&pge_id= 5`
In that `prsnl_pge.php` with the help of `window.history.pushState`. I have change that to`www.domainname.com/Page name`. It works successfully.

But when I try to reload that page 404 error appears. Can anyone one help me to sort this out?

Comment: this would probably require the rewrite to be done by your http server - .htaccess or some other method

Comment: Does www.domainname.com/Page exist?

Comment: www.domainname.com/Page exist it is not exist. I change www.domainname.com/userhome.php?view=prsnl_pge&pge_id= 5 to www.domainname.com/Page exist.

Comment: is there any chance specify url with the help of javascript when i try to reload page?

Comment: no there is not, since when you navigate to a new URL your browser needs to load javascript in which the logic will need to sit for that change... maybe service workers can give you what you want, but I am not sure.. The correct way that this should be done is using URLRewrite on your web server to translate your "pretty" url into the url your web servcer application can understand.